# Randomize math calculation where we subtract with percentage - node.js/js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hey :) You can subtract as example 35% from a number with methods like this:

```
var valueInString = "2383";
var num = parseFloat(valueInString);
var val = num - (num * .35);
console.log(val);
```

But how is it possible to randomize the .35/0.35 part?

As example if I would try:

```
var randomREAL = require('randomize');
var randomARR = [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75]
// randomREAL(randomARR) will generate a random number between 30 - 75 so that I can randomize my percentage value between 30% & 75%

var valueInString = "2383";
var num = parseFloat(valueInString);
var val = num - ( num * 0.randomREAL(randomARR) );
console.log(val);
```

I can´t use

```
0.randomREAL(randomARR)
```

or

```
.randomREAL(randomARR)
```

Also If I would build a string like

```
var test = randomREAL(randomARR)
0.test
```

it would not work.

Any ideas how to randomize the percentage value ?

Comment: how about `var val = num - ( num * ( randomREAL( randomARR ) / 100 ) )` ?

Comment: Hey cool thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
+("0."+randomARR[ Math.floor( randomARR.length * Math.random() ) ])
```

As youve pointed out

> Also If I would build a string like
>
> var test = randomREAL(randomARR)
>      0.test
>
> it would not work.

Because `0.` is not a string. You want string concatenation e.g.:

```
"0."+35
```

And then you need to parse it back into a number, which can be done with the `unary plus operator` :

```
+("0."+35)
```

Additionally if the number is always two digits, you can also use `/100`...

Hint: To get a random integer between 30 and 75 is as easy as:

```
30 + Math.floor( Math.random() * ( 75 - 30 ))
```

Comment: This worked for me var val = num - ( num * ("0."+randomREAL(randomARR)) ) thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

To easily get random numbers between an interval you can use this very simple function from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
 min = Math.ceil(min);
 max = Math.floor(max);
 return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min; //The maximum is exclusive and the minimum is inclusive
}
```